# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement, innodb

Hi I have the following code which seem to just want to not work, I have done code the same which has worked fine before so I don't quite know why it is not working now. It returns the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in... "

This is the Php pdo function I call to edit the database:

```
public function update_email_validation($params)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('
            UPDATE email_validation
            SET status=:status
            WHERE email=:email
            AND hash=:hash
            AND status!=:status
            LIMIT 1');

    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $params['status'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $params['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hash', $params['hash'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

And then this is the call from php passing the array along:

```
if ($db->update_email_validation(
       ['status' => 1,
        'email' => $params['email'],
        'hash' => $params['hash']]
    ) == 0)
{

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: 4 placeholders + 3 variables = bad time

Comment: @bassxzero is right. You're using 4 placeholders in your query but only pass 3 values to them. I understand 2 placeholders are the same but if I remember correctly, PDO doesn't recognise that. Try changing the second and `:status` with something else and pass the same value to it

Comment: turn on pdo emulation

Comment: Sadly, it isn't mandatory for PDO drivers to support name-based parameters that are used more than once (call it bug of feature). In MySQL they work or not depending on whether you use native or emulated prepared statements.